# Turn CSV file into array using Vanilla Javascript without input element

Tags: javascript, photoshop-script

I am trying to read turn a CSV file, the file is on local, could be same folder with the script file. Since I am writing JSX for photoshop, I couldn't use any other library. And there are a lot of tutorial out there using input element which is not what I need. The path of the file could be hard coded. What I am trying to do is read the CSV, and take out some data. Please advise!

Let me explain it clearly!
I am writing JSX for photoshop script which has no browser element - input tag something like that. And it must be pure Javascript no library such as jQuery. I did a lot of google search what they do is taking the input tag from browser let user select the CSV file, I just want the file path is hard code, it is a fixed path and filename. And I don't see any tutorial for read CSV file and turn into array via vanilla javascript.

Comment: Please show us more of you core...

Comment: Sorry, let me explain clearly, I am writing JSX for photoshop script which has no browser element - input tag something like that. And it must be pure Javascript no library such as jQuery. I did a lot of google search what they do is taking the input tag from browser let user select the CSV file, I just want the file path is hard code, it is a fixed path and filename. And I don't see any tutorial for read CSV file and turn into array via vanilla javascript.

Comment: The keyword you need for efficiently googling this is `ExtendScript`.

Comment: yes! I found the exactly code by search ExtendScript, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `File` class. How this works is explained in the ExtendScript toolkit docs which are installed on your computer alongside Creative Cloud. An online version can also be found [here](https://extendscript.docsforadobe.dev/file-system-access/index.html). (The [scripting guide](https://github.com/Adobe-CEP/CEP-Resources/raw/master/Documentation/Product%20specific%20Documentation/Photoshop%20Scripting/photoshop-javascript-ref-2020.pdf) references this under the `File` object on page 110, referring to a section about JavaScript on different platforms on page 32, which then refers to the ExtendScript docs.)

Example:

```js
const file = new File("/c/Users/user/Desktop/text.csv");
file.encoding = 'UTF-8';
file.open("r");
const contents = file.read();
file.close();

alert(contents);
```